# How to use output of data resource in other resource using terraform

Tags: terraform, jfrog-cli

I am trying to connect to the jfrog artifatory using

```
provider "artifactory" {
  url           = "url"
  access_token  = "token"
}
```

I amrefering link to [read repos from artifactory](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/jfrog/artifactory/latest/docs/data-sources/repositories#repos)

```
data "artifactory_repositories" "repositories" {
  project_key     = "key"
  repository_type = "local"
  package_type    = "pypi"
}
```

Trying to install repo using below code in other resource

```
library {
  pypi {
    package = "fbprophet==0.6"
    repo    = data.artifactory_repositories.repositories.url
  }
}
```

I am getting an error while installing repo

> This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "url".

How to use the output from data resouce and veridy if the connection to artifactory is successful?

Comment: I think it might be `data.artifactory_repositories.repositories.repos[*].url`.

Comment: Thanks Marko, It worked but it seems repos is empty. `data.artifactory_repositories.repositories.repos is empty set of object` How to verify/debug if the connection to artifactory is successful?

Comment: Are you sure the values you are providing to the data source are actually returning anything? In other words, are you sure the repository (or repositories) exist which satisfy the filtering values you provided?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you've linked to says that the data source has a property named [repos](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/jfrog/artifactory/latest/docs/data-sources/repositories#read-only), which is a list of repositories.

So you probably just want the first element in the list (unless you're finding more than one). Maybe try something like this:

```
repo = data.artifactory_repositories.repositories.repos[0].url
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil, I had tried it before but it throws the error `This value does not have any indices.`

Comment: How to verify/debug if the connection to artifactory is successful, it seems the repos is returned empty

Comment: You can enable detailed logs by setting the TF_LOG environment variable. The log levels available are TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, and ERROR. Setting TF_LOG to DEBUG will provide verbose output suitable for troubleshooting. You can enable it as: TF_LOG=debug terraform plan

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, if the debug logs don't help I would suggest altering how you search for the repo. Maybe omit the `key` property and just rely on the `package_type` to see if it finds anything...